# Getting error while trying to add a java date as literal in spark dataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have defined a variable like this in my scala notebook .

```
import java.time.{LocalDate, LocalDateTime, ZoneId, ZoneOffset, Duration}
val fiscalYearStartDate = LocalDate.of(fiscalStartYear,7,1);
```

I would like to add this as column to my dataFrame.

```
SomeDF.lit(fiscalYearStartDate ).cast("date").as("fiscalYearStartDate")
```

This is throwing an error .
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.time.LocalDate 2020-10-01

Comment: try to string and cast as date

Comment: @Lamanus , yeah that worked !!

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL DateType eqivalent in Scala is java.sql.Date and as result solution could be on of:

```
val finalDF = SomeDF.withColumn("fiscalYearStartDate", lit(fiscalYearStartDate.toString).cast("Date"))
```

or

```
val finalDF = SomeDF.withColumn("fiscalYearStartDate", lit(fiscalYearStartDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")).cast("Date"))
```

or

```
import java.sql.Date
val finalDF = SomeDF.withColumn("fiscalYearStartDate", lit(Date.valueOf(fiscalYearStartDate)))
```